# Scoping of a variable outside of its function context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of code:

**2-iife.js**

```js
    const counter = (function() {
            let count = 0
    
            return {
                    inc: function() { count = count + 1 },
                    get: function() { console.log(count) },
            }
    })()
    
    counter.get()
    counter.inc()
    counter.get()
```

And it prints out:

> 0

> 1

I expect an **object** like this:

```
{
    inc: function() { count = count + 1 },
    get: function() { console.log(count) },
}
```

to be assigned to the `counter` constant variable.

Then how the heck does the `counter.get()` know what `count` even is to print out or increment it as I invoke `counter.get()` and `counter.inc()`?

Comment: Because of closure...

Comment: `const counter = (function() {` <-- the opening curly brace here opens a closure, anything inside can still be accessed